# Reading two dimensional pl/sql array

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am able to insert values but failed to retrieve values. Thanks in anticipation.

```
declare
  type type1 is table of number;
  type data_type is table of type1;
  y data_type;
begin
  y := data_type();
  y.extend(100);
  for i in 1..100 loop
    y(i) := type1();
    y(i).extend(100);
    for j in 1..100 loop
      y(i)(j) := i+j; 
    end loop;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: What is your question? Is there a problem with the code you have shown, or do you need to do something else that it doesn't currently do?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you need a way to scan your arrays;
this could be a way:

```
declare
  type type1 is table of number;
  type data_type is table of type1;
  y data_type;
  k number := 2;
begin
  y := data_type();
  y.extend(k);
  for i in 1..k loop
    y(i) := type1();
    y(i).extend(k);
    for j in 1..k loop
      y(i)(j) := i+j; 
    end loop;
  end loop;
  -- scanning
  for i in y.first .. y.last loop
    for j in y(i).first .. y(i).last loop
        dbms_output.put_line('Y(' || i || ')(' || j || ') = ' || y(i)(j));
    end loop;
  end loop;
end;
```

the result:

```
Y(1)(1) = 2
Y(1)(2) = 3
Y(2)(1) = 3
Y(2)(2) = 4
```

Comment: while scanning, the inner j loop gives error 'ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection' during run time but no compilation error i'm using oracle 11g